# how to remove the back button on the flutter page?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have one problem that I cannot solve in any way. In the main file, I registered the routes. And provided that the "email" variable is not empty, the application is launched from the main page, and if empty from the authorization page. The problem is that when the application is launched from the home page, a back (return to home) arrow appears on that page. It is possible to somehow hide this arrow (as a butobe, I use pushReplacementNamed). I would be grateful for your help.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:mobile_weight/model/PageScanQR/ScanPage.dart';
import 'package:mobile_weight/model/Login_Page/LoginPage.dart';
import 'package:mobile_weight/model/Setting_page/setting_glob.dart';



Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var email = prefs.getString('email');
  print(email);
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: email == null ? '/' : '/scan',
    routes: {
      '/' : (context) => Login(),
      '/scan' : (context) => Form_scan(),
      '/setting' : (context) => Setting(),
    },
  ));
}
```

My home page

```html
class Form_scan extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Scan'), backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,),
      body: SealsPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to remove back button from AppBar in Page?

Comment: @ArulMani i edit my queshion , and add code home page)

Comment: @ArulMani yes, in appBar

Answer (score 3):

try automaticallyImplyLeading:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(automaticallyImplyLeading: false, title: Text('Scan'), backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,),
      body: SealsPage(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: thank you) this is what you need, but you can still disable the button back to android ??

Comment: willPopScope is your friend, WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return shouldPop;
      },
      child: Scaffold(